# Python regex find single digit if no digits before it

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have a list of strings and I want to use regex to get a single digit if there are no digits before it.

```
strings = ['5.8 GHz', '5 GHz']

for s in strings:
    print(re.findall(r'\d\s[GM]?Hz', s))

# output
['8 GHz']
['5 GHz']

# desired output
['5 GHz']
```

I want it to just return '5 GHz', the first string shouldn't have any matches. How can I modify my pattern to get the desired output?

Comment: Do you mean you want to include the "^" at the start of your pattern? Effectively outputting an empty list on the 1st "s".

Comment: No, because I have other strings which start with other characters and sentences so I need a general solution

Comment: Maybe it's wise to reflect that type of data in your sample. Looking at what you wrote now, you could see if `r'(?<!\d\.)\d+\s[GM]?Hz'` does the trick?

Comment: That works too, but could you explain why the first bit is in brackets?

Comment: It's a negative lookbehind to prevent capturing a fraction instead of integer. Now you can find matches inside any string like "Test 4 anything 2 include any 1 Hz inside this string" and still get your results. A very general solution as you mentioned.

Comment: That works perfectly! If you post it as an answer, I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment, it seems that you can use:

```
(?<!\d\.)\d+\s[GM]?Hz\b
```

This matches:

- `(?<!\d\.)` - A negative lookbehind to assert position is not right after any single digit and literal dot.
- `\d+` - 1+ numbers matching the integer part of the frequency.
- `[GM]?Hz` - An optional uppercase G or M followed by "Hz".
- `\b` - A word boundary.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> strings = ['5.8 GHz', '5 GHz']
>>> 
>>> for s in strings:
...     match = re.match(r'^[^0-9]*([0-9] [GM]Hz)', s)
...     if match:
...         print(match.group(1))
... 
5 GHz
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated Answer

```py
import re
a = ['5.8 GHz', '5 GHz', '8 GHz', '1.2', '1.2 Some Random String', '1 Some String', '1 MHz of frequency', '2 Some String in Between MHz']
res = []
for fr in a:
    if re.match('^[0-9](?=.[^0-9])(\s)[GM]Hz$', fr):
        res.append(fr)
print(res)
```

Output:
`['5 GHz', '8 GHz']`

Comment: This works, but sometimes I'll have cases where there is more than just "GHz" after the number, so the pattern should include "GHz". Can you edit your pattern to look for this specifically?

Comment: Are you saying that GHz should match as well, since your list could be this as well
`['5.8 GHz', '5 GHz', '8 GHz', '1.2', '4.5 Some_Random_Text']` and among them you only need `GHz` or `MHz`, i.e frequencies

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please let me know if you need something more

Comment: This Updated answer contains all the possible test cases that I think of, please let me know if you have an another test case in mind. For all those above test cases it is working perfectly fine

Answer (score 0):

My two cents:

```py
selected_strings = list(filter(
    lambda x: re.findall(r'(?:^|\s+)\d+\s+(?:G|M)Hz', x),
    strings
))
```

With `['2 GHz', '5.8 GHz', '   5 GHz', '3.4 MHz', '3 MHz', '1 MHz of Frequency']` as `strings`, here `selected_strings`:

```py
['2 GHz', '   5 GHz', '3 MHz', '1 MHz of Frequency']
```

Comment: Hello PieCot, can you update your regex for the string `1 MHz of Frequency`, since it is getting filtered along with the answer :)

Comment: Actually, I've tried it, and it worked. I added it to the example strings.